# How to convert N space separated numbers into in array in Python?

Tags: python

How do I input *n* integers separated by space in Python?

Suppose I want to input *n* elements in an array separated by space such as

```
3
1 2 3
```

In the first line we are given *n* and in the next line *n* inputs follow. How can I store them in an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways:

1. using `input()`<sup>1</sup> and. This prompts the user to enter inputs:

   ```
   int_list = [int(x) for x in input("Enter integers:").split()]
   ```

   `.split()` separates the values in the input by spaces.
2. using `sys.argv`, you can specify input from the command line

   ```
   import sys
   int_list = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>`raw_input()` in Python 2

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers: ") #ask for input

numbersArray = [] #array to store the input

for number in numbers:
    numbersArray.append(number) #add input to the array
```

Not that at this point if for example the input is `1 2 3` then the array looks like this:
 `['1',' ','2',' ','3']` so you have to remove the `' '` from it:

`numbersArray = numbersArray[::2]`

Now testing with this input `1 2 3` calling `print(numbersArray);` will output `['1', '2', '3']`.