# How to input elements in list in one line seperated by space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which takes n elements as input in it. Everything is fine but I want to take the input in same line separated by space. How can I modify my below code?

```
a = int(input("Enter size of list: "))
print("Enter elements:")
l = [int(input()) for i in range(a)]    
print(l)
```

My output:

```
Enter size of list: 3
Enter elements:
1
2
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Enter size of list: 3
Enter elements:
1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
```

I had tried this one ([Input n elements seperated by space in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910255/input-n-elements-seperated-by-space-in-python)) but it didn't satisfied what I need because it's for a dynamic list but I want for a static list according to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for? Using `enumerate()` to limit to your static value.

```py
a = int(input("Enter size of list: "))
print("Enter elements:")
l = [int(z) for y, z in enumerate(input().split()) if y < a and z.isdigit()]
print(l)
```

output:

```
Enter size of list: 3
Enter elements:
1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
```

other output:

```
Enter size of list: 3
Enter elements:
1 2 3 a b c 5
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks dude :D
Yes this is what I was searching for many weeks

Comment: can you please explain me the logic

Comment: @AvishekDattaRay, glad it's what you wanted. [Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) provides a counter. So checking the counter with your size limits the result. Just added the `isdigit()` to skip non-numerics. If you need anything additional, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use the string split method: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

```
l = input().split(" ")
l = [int x for x in l]
```

Comment: But it's a dynamic list... As per my code the list iterates in a certain range. In simple, it's working as a static array. I just want to take the elements in single in that static list

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. If you only want the first 3 elements, you can do `l = l[:3]`, or `l = l[:a]` in this case

Comment: No not 1st 3 elements. I want to accept a list of size n taking inputs in it separated by space. As per my code the I have to take one element in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python map function to map given input string to int array

```
list(map(int , input().split()))
```

Comment: This is same as this one - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910255/input-n-elements-seperated-by-space-in-python) but my requirement is not restricted up to this much